# Outlook Add-in's Node.js Using Bcrypt Error?

Tags: node.js, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Outlook Add-In and using bcrypt on my application, I require the module on my **taskpane.js** file but when I run the command `npm run build` it gives me an **error** below, I can't paste all the lines of the error because of the post limit.

```
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/infer-owner/index.js 2:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\infer-owner'
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/util/fix-owner.js 8:19-41
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/lib/entry-index.js 13:17-44
 @ ./node_modules/cacache/index.js 10:14-45
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/entry.js 6:16-34
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/cache/index.js 2:19-40
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js 7:14-41
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js 4:14-35
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js 12:14-42
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/ip/lib/ip.js 3:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\ip\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
 @ ./node_modules/socks/build/client/socksclient.js 15:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/socks/build/index.js 17:13-44
 @ ./node_modules/socks-proxy-agent/dist/index.js 16:16-32
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js 161:24-52
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js 7:17-38
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js 8:15-37
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js 4:14-35
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js 12:14-42
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/index.js 1:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\isexe'
 @ ./node_modules/which/which.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./build.js ./build
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/mode.js 4:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\isexe'
 @ ./node_modules/isexe/index.js 6:9-29
 @ ./node_modules/which/which.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./build.js ./build
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/windows.js 4:9-22
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\isexe'
 @ ./node_modules/isexe/index.js 4:9-32
 @ ./node_modules/which/which.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js 7:14-30
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./build.js ./build
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/make-dir/index.js 2:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\make-dir'
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js 13:16-35
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js 3:12-26
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'url' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "url": require.resolve("url/") }'
        - install 'url'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "url": false }
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js 7:17-38
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js 8:15-37
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js 4:14-35
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js 12:14-42
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/agent.js 50:16-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "https": require.resolve("https-browserify") }'
        - install 'https-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "https": false }
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/remote.js 7:17-38
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/fetch.js 8:15-37
 @ ./node_modules/make-fetch-happen/lib/index.js 4:14-35
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/install.js 12:14-42
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/node-gyp/lib/node-gyp.js 41:13-36 191:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js 31:26-53
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./util/compile.js ./util/compile
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

...

ERROR in ./node_modules/tar/lib/write-entry.js 5:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\tar\lib'
 @ ./node_modules/tar/index.js 15:0-52
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js 16:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

ERROR in ./node_modules/tar/node_modules/minipass/index.js 10:15-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Users\jicc\Documents\QuickBase\node_modules\tar\node_modules\minipass'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false }
 @ ./node_modules/tar/lib/pack.js 25:17-36
 @ ./node_modules/tar/index.js 11:0-39
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/install.js 16:12-26
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/ sync ^\.\/.*$ ./install.js ./install
 @ ./node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/node-pre-gyp.js 86:13-36 291:36-53
 @ ./node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js 3:17-48
 @ ./src/taskpane/taskpane.js 11:13-30

115 errors have detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.76.3 compiled with 117 errors and 4 warnings in 16140 ms
```

**How do I solve the error or where do I suppose to require the module on my project?**

Comment: Sounds like you need to upgrade webpack to versions greater than 5. Have you tried creating a new add-in solution using yeoman generator? Do you get any problems in that case?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev tried updating the webpack versions that but didn't work at all, also create the add-in using yeoman generator.

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest version of webpack installed on your machine. Then you can scaffold a new add-in and try running it. That should help.

Comment: I have a webpack version `webpack@5.81.0`, and what do you mean scaffold a new add-in? do you mean to create a new add-in? a did that, I created a new add-in after I finished installing the latest version of the webpack but still the same error when I run the command **npm run build**

Comment: do you get it with a clean newly generated solution? or after installing any other dependencies?

Comment: I get the error when I use **bcrypt** or even just declare **bcrypt** on **taskpane.js** file, try installing **bcrypt** and declare it on your **taskpane.js** file and run the command `npm run build` you will get the error but if you don't use **bcrypt** running the command `npm run build` has no problem

Comment: So, you don't get any issues when dealing with a newly generated solution, right?

Comment: yes! no issues at all, the problem is when using bcrypt library that's where the issues occur

Comment: Well, you need to post that issue to the bcrypt developers then, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt  for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The key part of that set of error is the message "webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default. This is no longer the case."

The projects created by yeoman are setup to transpile (via webpack) the src to java scaript that is compatible with older standards that work in IE (older versions of Office still use the IE webview to load taskpanes).  Webpack is trying to use libraries for this polyfill (a dependency requirement introduced by including bcrypt in the project) that it no longer provides "out of the box".  To fix it, follow the instructions given in the message for each pacakge mentioned.

For example, the first thing missing is the reference to 'os' and so it says
"If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
- add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
- install 'os-browserify'".

So you need to

- run 'npm install os-browserify --save-dev'
- Edit webpack.config.js file's "resolve" section to have a fallback object with "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") as a property.

The webpack documentation this can be found at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolvefallback

Comment: there are still a lot of errors even if I did that, tried fixing all the errors but another error occurred when you tried fixing them.

Comment: Updating webpack and office/yeoman generator to the latest version helped me to scaffold a new add-in solution which works correctly. But with old samples I constantly have a pain in my head.

Comment: Updated webpack and office/yeoman generator to the latest version but still the same error running command `npm run build` when I insert `const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');` on my **taskpane.js** file, maybe you are not using bcrypt and you did not insert `const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');` on your **taskpane.js** file because that has no problem when you run the command `npm run build`

Comment: Not all the errors indicate the specific module that is needed, but they are essentially the same thing . . . bcrypt requires modules that were part of node, but are not provided automatically.  You need to figure out what modules to install and reference in webpack.config.js, or indicate 'false' for fallback for that module (like 'fs: false' instead of resolving to a library).